# Versioning Semantic UI themes

Tags: css, bower, semantic-ui

It's either too late or I just can't figure out how to correctly make use of Semantic UI theming and co.

Within my repository I just want to have my theme configurations and overrides, not every single file of Semantic UI.

I tried to install Semantic UI with Bower, but it seems like I have to build it myself that way (which would be pretty annoying since I'm not using Gulp but Grunt).

Installing it with NPM confuses me a bit. Where to put my configuration files that way?